# To do display the last week of data and the data between any two dates I am struggling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried moment.js and tried to use jquery daypicker. but somewhat nothing really work so far. I think when I tried to use these methods I missed something or I used wrong.

As you see below my code I could make  'display the last of month' one with just basic vanilla javascript. but I want to make this one better two. 
I've been working on this almost a week now. I think it's time to ask help ...

In my js file:

```
 'use strict';
    require('./create-data-table.scss');
    const angular = require('angular');
    // const moment = require('moment');
    const sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp');

    sampleApp.component('createDataTable',{
      template: require('./create-data-table.html'),
      controller: 'CreateTableController',
      controllerAs:'createTableCtrl'
    });

    sampleApp.factory('listsFactory', function($q,$http){
      return {
        getLists: function(){
          return  $http.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/evanjacobs/c150c0375030dc4de65e9b95784dc894/raw/35c5f455b147703db3989df0cb90f5781c3b312f/usage_data.json');
        }
      };
    });

    sampleApp.controller('CreateTableController', ['$scope', '$http','listsFactory', CreateTableController]);

    function CreateTableController($scope,$http, listsFactory){
      // $scope.date ={ year:null, month:null};
      listsFactory.getLists().then(function(response){
        $scope.lists = response.data;
        console.log($scope.lists);
      }, function(error){
        console.error(error);
      });
      $scope.reverse = function() {
        $scope.lists.reverse();
      };
      $scope.sortingByMonthFilter = function(year, month) {
        console.log('filtering');
        $scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.unfilteredLists || $scope.lists;
        $scope.lists = $scope.unfilteredLists.filter((record) => {
          return record.date.includes(`${year}-${month}`);
        });
      };

      $scope.getLastWeek = function() {
        $scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.lists;
        $scope.lists = $scope.lists.filter((record) => {
          var today = new Date();
          var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
          var currentMonth = today.getMonth();
          var currentDay = today.getDate();
          var recordDate =  new Date(record.date);
          var recordYear = recordDate.getFullYear();
          var recordMonth = recordDate.getMonth();
          var recordDay = recordDate.getDate();
          var lastWeekDays = [];
          var firstDayOfLastWeek = currentDay -7;

          for(var i = currentDay; i >= firstDayOfLastWeek; i--){
            lastWeekDays.push(i);
          }
          var lastWD1 = lastWeekDays[0];
          var lastWD2 = lastWeekDays[1];
          var lastWD3 = lastWeekDays[2];
          var lastWD4 = lastWeekDays[3];
          var lastWD5 = lastWeekDays[4];
          var lastWD6 = lastWeekDays[5];
          var lastWD7 = lastWeekDays[6];

          if (recordYear === currentYear && recordMonth === currentMonth){
            console.log(recordYear,recordMonth, currentYear,currentMonth);
            // if(recordDay.matches(lastWeekDays)){
            //   return record;
            // }
            if (recordDay=== lastWD1|| lastWD2||lastWD3||   
                lastWD4||lastWD5|| lastWD6||lastWD7){
              console.log(record);
              return record;
            }
          }
          else {
            console.log('No matching data!');
          }
        });
      };

      $scope.getLastMonth = function(){
        $scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.lists;
        $scope.lists = $scope.lists.filter((record) => {
          var today = new Date();
          var currentMonth = today.getMonth();
          var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
          var recordDate =  new Date(record.date);
          var recordYear = recordDate.getFullYear();
          var recordMonth = recordDate.getMonth();
          var lastMonth = currentMonth -1;
          if (recordYear === currentYear){
            if (recordMonth === lastMonth && lastMonth !== 0 ){
              console.log(record);
              return record;
            }
            if(recordMonth === lastMonth && lastMonth === 0 ){
              recordYear = currentYear -1;
              recordMonth = 11;
              return record;
            }
          }
        });
      };
      $scope.byTwoDates = function(){
        $scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.lists;
        $scope.lists = $scope.lists.filter((record) => {
          // function daysBetween(startDate, endDate){
          //   var days = [], current = startDate;
          //   while(current <= endDate){
          //     days.push(current);
          //   }
          //   return days;
          // }
          var startD = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
          var endD = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
          console.log(startD,endD);
          var currentDate = new Date(startD);
          var d =[];
          console.log(d);
        });
      };

      $scope.sortType = 'name';
      $scope.sortReverse = false;
      $scope.searchData = '';

    }
```

In my html

```
  <div class ="create-data-table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <section class="bylastMonth">
            <button name="filter" ng-click="getLastMonth()">Last Month Data</button>
          </section>
          <section class="bylastWeek">
            <button name="filter" ng-click="getLastWeek()">Last Week Data</button>
          </section>
          <section class="bytwoDays">
            <!-- <input id="startDate"/>
            <input id="endDate"/> -->

            <label>Start Date</label><input id="startDate" type="date">
            <label>End Date</label><input id="endDate" type="date">
            <button name="filter" ng-click="byTwoDates()">Between Two days</button>
          </section>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              Date
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'date' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'date' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
            <section class="filteringByMonth">
              <input name="year" type="text" placeholder ="Year" ng-model="date.year" >
              <input name="month" type="text" placeholder="Month(MM)" ng-model="date.month" >
              <button name="filter" ng-click="sortingByMonthFilter(date.year, date.month)">Filter</button>
            </section>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'users'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Users
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'users' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'users' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </div>
                    <input type="text"
                     name ="users"
                     class="form-control" placeholder="search by Users #" ng-model="searchData">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'searches'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Searches
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'searches' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'searches' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="list in lists | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | 
         filter:searchData">
          <td>{{ list.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.users }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.searches }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
```

SAVE ME!

Comment: That's a lot of code with very little explanation.  What's working?  What's not working?  Are there errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and https://github.com/urish/angular-moment so then you need to change your `byTwoDates` function a bit and make it like

```
$scope.byTwoDates = function(start, end) {
    try {
      return ((moment.duration(end - start)).humanize());
    } catch (e) {
      return "It's not valid to evaluate"
    }
  };
```

If you want to getLastWeek you may use of the following method:

This week:

```
moment().startOf('isoWeek')
moment().endOf('isoWeek')
```

Last Week

```
moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek')
moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek')
```

See this document: http://momentjs.com/docs/

as an example

```
     /*getLastWeekStart().format('DD/MM/YYYY') to get 10/09/2016 */


     function getNextWeekStart() {  // Just for demonestration if you want to work with next week you can leave this function. 
            var today = moment();
            //edited part
            var daystoMonday = 0 - (today.isoWeekday() - 1) + 7;       
            var nextMonday = today.subtract('days', daystoMonday);

            return nextMonday;
        }

        function getLastWeekStart() {
            var today = moment();
            var daystoLastMonday = 0 - (1 - today.isoWeekday()) + 7;

            var lastMonday = today.subtract('days', daystoLastMonday);

            return lastMonday;
        }

        function getLastWeekEnd() {
            var lastMonday = getLastWeekStart();
            var lastSunday = lastMonday.add('days', 6);

            return lastSunday; 
        }

    //remember you may also use this 
    moment('anydate you want ').weekday(-7).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

please feel free to add whatever you want to this function and customize it.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer! I can't believe how all the problem can solve this easy way with angular-moment module! but I have problem.

Comment: my webpack complains about angular-ui-boostrap and moment. googled to fix this problem. no luck yet.

Comment: wondering If there's any recomendation for this problem. my package.json has both. and I required them in index.js file and injected in my controller and my app module. still and I tried to add in bundle.js it didn't work either. and tried to change webpack.config file following other google search recomendation.

Comment: I was using fontawsome before downloaded angular-ui-bootstrap but I removed it totally to avoid conflicts.